# How to enable cURL in PHP / XAMPP

Tags: php, curl, xampp

How do I enable cURL in PHP?

​​

Comment: windoze or linux?

Comment: windows. Thanks David. i solved it.. Actually i did it by uncommenting the extension=php_curl.dllin the xampp\apache\bin\php.ini file

Comment: A basic curl tutorial very easy to learn -> http://www.technofusions.com/curl-in-php-tutorial-basics/

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Since you're using XAMPP, uncomment the line

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

in `xampp\apache\bin\php.ini`, and then restart the Apache service.

NB: In newer XAMPP versions, PHP has moved to root xampp folder `xampp\php\php.ini`.

Answer (score 227):

On [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) with [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) 2:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

(php4-curl if it's php4)

Comment: Note the restart is necessary.

Comment: +1 to @Nelson. The post install /looks/ like it does a restart, but it really does a reload.

Comment: Nelson: It shouldn't be necessary, but it was for me. Even though apt-get restarted apache, it didn't work until I restarted it myself a 2nd time. Strange.

Comment: If it fails, try to update repositories with "apt-get update"

Comment: Also it wasn't sufficient to *reload* apache. I had to *restart* it.

Comment: Simple. Very nice

Answer (score 21):

Steps for Windows 7:

1. Ensure that the php.ini file that the PHP engine uses is the one you think it is.
2. Ensure extension_dir in php.ini is correctly set to the ext folder
3. Ensure `extension=php_curl.dll` in the php.ini is uncommented

Finally and maybe the one most people don't know:
4. Ensure that there are these two files in the Windows System32 folder:
       libeay32.dll
       ssleay32.dll
If not there, you may copy these two files from the `php` folder.

Comment: Actually, this wasn't the issue, since php isn't hosted in IIS, but in Apache(with wamp). It turns out that wamp came out with incompatible versions... had to add apache 2.2.9, and php 5.3.1, and use wami tray->Apache(or PHP)->Version->____ to switch to those versions, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10939248/79444

Comment: In addition to the 4th requirement, for win7 64bit, those 2 files should go C:\windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: @WaiKit Kung you are awesome..done the 4th step and worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: I had to add the following to my PHP code to get things to work: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: `Ensure extension_dir in php.ini is correctly set to the ext folder` 
That did the job for me.

Answer (score 11):

I found the file located at:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

Uncommented:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu (and probably all Debian-Based) Linux Distributions:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

You might have seen `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init()` before.

Answer (score 6):

In [SUSE Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_distributions):

```
zypper in php5-curl
rcapache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

You [compile your PHP using `--with-curl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php).

Answer (score 3):

Since XAMPP went through some modifications, the file is now at `xampp/php/php.ini`.

Answer (score 3):

Basic tip: After enabling the CURL in php.ini file, you need to restart the web server to make it work (my experience says).

Answer (score 3):

PHP 7^ version:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: sudo service apache2 reload works too, I believe the reload is more indicated to not stop the server.

Answer (score 2):

If you're are using [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP), [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I did it by uncommenting `extension=php_curl.dll` in the xampp\apache\bin\php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `phpinfo()` (create a script containing   and browse to it). This will tell you if you really do have it enabled. If not, read [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html).

It is not recommended for the faint-hearted Windows developer.

Comment: nope Mark.. I am in need to ENABLE cURL support exactly. Actually i did it by uncommenting the 
extension=php_curl.dllin the xampp\apache\bin\php.ini file . But it does not reflect. Any more Idea

Comment: Did you restart xampp? 
Did you get an error in your xampp log file? 
Do you have php_curl.dll in your xampp php extensions directory?

Answer (score 0):

For windows OS users (It worked for me) in XAMPP.

step 1: Go to C:\xampp\php\php.ini

edit this file php.ini

find curl- you will see a line ;extension=php_curl.dll.

remove semicolon (;)extension=php_curl.dll. so this line looks like

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

step 2:
copy ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll from php folder.
paste  it in C:\Windows\System32\

step 3:
Restart the system . Curl will run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

check if curl module is available

```
$ ls -la /etc/php5/mods-available/
```

enable the curl module

```
$ sudo php5enmod curl
```

source:
http://baligena.com/installing-curl-ubuntu-server/

Answer (score 0):

Check the php version,
If you installed php 7.0 version

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you installed php 5.6 version

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solves your problem and have installed with php-x86 (Windows 32 bit), then problem may be of openssl - for more info : [How to fix libeay32.dll was not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534505/how-to-fix-libeay32-dll-was-not-found-error)

Answer (score -1):

to install `php5-curl` under opensuse:

```
sudo yast2
```

->software ->software management ->search for curl ->check php5-curl case and accept.

after installation you need to restart apache server

```
service apache2 restart
```