# How to fix libeay32.dll was not found error

Tags: curl

I want to run some url, i used curl in windows environment for it.i downloaded curl executable from http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win64 and saved curl.exe  in C drive than i just open the command prompt and type:
C:\curl http://google.com but it is giving me error: libeay32.dll was not found.

though i have this dll file in archive, How can i fix this problem

Answer (score 15):

It is a library from SSL. You need to install [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html).

You might also meet missing `readline()` function in python. You have to install pyreadline Lib.

Answer (score 11):

For windows, you need to download the latest version of the open SSL binaries at
this time is:

```
openssl-1.0.2k-x64_86-win64.zip
```

[image: openSSL list]

this problem happened to me when I tried to run **MongoDB** bin in windows 10

source to download:
https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem when I tried to install [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/) in my 32 bit win 7 machine. As answered by Buravchik it is indeed dependency of SSL and installing [openssl](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) fixed it. Just a point to take care is that while installing openssl you will get a prompt to ask where do you wish to put the dependent DLLS.  Make sure to put it in windows system directory as other programs like **curl** and **wget** will also be needing it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to put the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll files in the systems folder

Answer (score 2):

Download libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll binary package for 32Bit and 64Bit from http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ then put it into executable or System32 directory.

Comment: This does not have the latest versions of Win32 Openssl

Comment: now it has latest version

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this kind of problem before. I was using the Windows x64 operating system, so I was getting an error in openssl. Later I realized that the path to the OpenSSL installation file was "C: \ OpenSSL win32". Finally, I deleted the OpenSSL program and installed it to "C: \ Program Files (x86)" and used it smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the dll in application is of the same version as that in the sys32 or wow64 folder depending on your version of windows.

You can *check that from the **filesize** of the dlls*.

Eg: I faced this issue because my libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll file in system32 had a different dll than my libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll file in openssl application.

> I copied the one in sys32 into openssl and everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem so, after install visual studpo redistributable 2012 and 2013 all have been solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).