# Visual Studio - Build project works without problems but files .dll are missing

Tags: visual-studio, libraries

When I compile the project everything works fine but when I run it keeps throwing errors saying that .dll files are missing.

Using Visual Studio 17.3.4

**CMake configuration**

```
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR openssl/install_dir/include)
set(OPENSSL_LIBRARIES openssl/install_dir/lib/libeay32.lib openssl/install_dir/lib/ssleay32.lib)
       
include_directories(AFTER ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}) 
target_link_libraries(executable_name ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
```

**Error:** The code execution can`t continue because libeay32.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have openSSL installed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534505/how-to-fix-libeay32-dll-was-not-found-error

Comment: No. But if I am using a .lib (static library) my compiled code will contain everything that is needed or not ?

Comment: You can fix it by placing required *.dll in the directory with your executable in ${project_dir}/out/build/x64-Debug/. But I think it is a bad solution. Wish to know is there any other way