# cURL / wp_remote_post: won't work in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, curl

I'm working on a wordpress plugin, which pull data from another site via a cURL post call. I've tested the same code in i wordpress plugin and outsite of wordpress.

Outsite of wordpress the script works fine, but inside a wordpress plugin, the script just wont work:

Wordpress plugin:

```
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL,             $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST,            true );
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,  true );
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,      array('postfield' => 'postfieldcontent'));

$result = curl_exec($handle);
```

Main site:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (q, w, e, r, t, y, u) VALUES ('', '".$_POST[postfield]."', '', '', '', '', '')");
```

I've removed all database security for debugging purpose. I have also tried the wp_remote_post function, that doesn't work either. I've even triede the the wp_remote_get function, but i can access the get variable:

```
$result = wp_remote_get( 'http://qwerty.dk/folder/filename.php?getfield=qwertrert' );
```

I've given up - please help :)

Best regards
Kim

Comment: Try `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'postfield=postfieldcontent');`

Comment: Hi safarov, Thank you for your input, but it doesn't work. It's like the postfield are not being sent :\

Answer (score 3):

You will need to enable cURL in your php.ini file.  See [#1347146](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php)

`wp_remote_post()` uses a class called `WP_Http` that in turn can use one of three transport classes (see file `class-http.php` function `_get_first_available_transport`).

POST method will work with class `WP_Http_Curl`, but will not work with class `WP_Http_Streams` (the cURL fallback).

The alternative is to use `wp_remote_get()`