# Got an error when i tried to login a website using facebook id

Tags: php, curl

Getting this error when I try to login using facebook id

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL
>   PHP extension.'

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is a long shot, but could it be because you don't have the CURL PHP extension installed?

Comment: Id say You dont have cURL installed.. :| But heres how to enable it for apache if thats what you use.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You don't have CURL installed or it is deactivated on your server.
 do phpinfo(); to see the if is installed.

Answer (score 0):

your server don't have Curl extension installed
.