# How to enable cURL extension on Amazon EC2 free tier

Tags: php, curl, amazon-ec2

I am currently trying to enable `cURL` on my EC2 server (free tier).

I have installed `php5_curl` and I am able to run curl through php via SSH.

I am using the following file to see whether cURL has been installed correctly.

testCurl.php

```
<?php
    function _iscurlsupported() {
            if (in_array ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
    }

    if (_iscurlsupported()) {
            echo "cURL is supported\n";
    }
    else {
            echo "cURL isn't supported\n";
    }
?>
```

The command via ssh: `php testCurl.php` displays that curl is supported.
The command when I access it through a brower displays that curl ISN'T supported.

I have checked the `php.ini` file located in php5/apache2 (the php.ini file that the browser loads (tested through another script)) and the extension is no where to be found.

I have checked the "extensions_dir" directory located on my server and the curl.so file is located there.

I am unsure why I am unable to run curl when accessing my script via the browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
jt234

Note: If you require any more information please ask.
My problem is similar (if not the same as) [Unable to use PHP curl on amazon ec2 free tier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598810/unable-to-use-php-curl-on-amazon-ec2-free-tier) but the issue hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Probably Amazon doesn't want you turning their free service into a webproxy.

Comment: Very unsporting of them!

Comment: Turns out you can. You have to manually add 'extension=curl.so' to the php.ini file located in apache2. (for future reference)

Comment: Which OS is this? Linux/windows? I have an Ubuntu server on ec2 free tier and i was able to get curl to work just by installing it(curl and php5-curl)!
Make sure you have made changes to the php.ini that apache-php is picking up. I think curl is enable for your php-cli but not you php over the webserver.

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598810/unable-to-use-php-curl-on-amazon-ec2-free-tier

Comment: is your problem solved? please close it then or flag it to the moderators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end of your php.ini file add the line:

```
extension=curl.so
```

if you want to find where it is located you can run over SSH:

```
$ locate curl.so
```

it should be in something close to: /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/curl.so