# PHP script works only in local host,not in Amazon?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am a very beginner so forgive me if its too basic .

I have set a localhost using `MAMP` and i have a `index.php` file that call me via `Twilio`, and its working great i get calls always:

```
<?php

$id = "ACxx15d26xxxxxxxxx454424bxxexx3f";
$token = "79fb4xxxf93c8exxxxxxxda6bxxxxe9 ";  
$url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$id/Calls.json";
$CallURL = "http://www.someweb.com";
$from = "+97223721333";
$to = "+971111111111"; // twilio trial verified number
$body = "Its all going to work!";
$data = array (
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Body' => $body,
    'Url' => $CallURL,  

);
$post = http_build_query($data);
$x = curl_init($url );
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_GET, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$id:$token");
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$y = curl_exec($x);
curl_close($x);
var_dump($post);
var_dump($y);
 ?>
```

Then i have set an `Amazon server EC2` , and i have put a few files in there (`filezilla`) which worked also(i can load images in the browser-and it works).

Then i have tried to put this file in the server, well there are 2 things happened.

1. when i put it as `index.php` , and browse there , i could see a *blank* page and nothing happened .
2. when i put it as `index.html` and browse there  , i have got this text ("which is not Json,so i dont know what it is) , and i **didn't** get the call also :

   > $from, 'To' => $to, 'Body' => $body, ); $post =
   >   http_build_query($data); $x = curl_init($url ); curl_setopt($x,
   >   CURLOPT_POST, true); curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   >   curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); curl_setopt($x,
   >   CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD,
   >   "$id:$token"); curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); $y =
   >   curl_exec($x); curl_close($x); var_dump($post); var_dump($y); */
   >   //twillio call $id = "ACa015xx662d50dxxx454424b70xxxxxx"; $token =
   >   "79fb4b00efxxc8exxxf772da6bxxxxxx "; //only after : in the website
   >   $url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$id/Calls.json";
   >   $CallURL = "http://www.somewebsite.com"; $from = "+97223721333"; $to =
   >   "+ 971111111111"; // twilio trial verified number $body = "Its all
   >   going to work!"; $data = array ( 'From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Body'
   >   => $body, 'Url' => $CallURL, ); $post = http_build_query($data); $x = curl_init($url ); curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_GET, true); curl_setopt($x,
   >   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,
   >   false); curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
   >   curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$id:$token"); curl_setopt($x,
   >   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); $y = curl_exec($x); curl_close($x);
   >   var_dump($post); var_dump($y); ?>

So , whats the different between putting it as `.php and .html` ? why is one of them is blank and the other has this respond ?

**EDIT**

I have tried to install curl with :  `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`(worked)

then i have tested to see if i have curl supported with this link:
[How to enable cURL extension on Amazon EC2 free tier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274346/how-to-enable-curl-extension-on-amazon-ec2-free-tier)
result is that its not supported.
Why is that ?  i have installed it.

Comment: One of them is blank because an error occurred. Your server probably hasn't got `curl` extension installed so it can't execute the code. `.html` on the other hand is simple text that browsers interpret into nice web pages - no server-side processing occurs there, you get served what's written in the file and that's why it works.

Comment: got you. php was installed. so i have to install curl ?

Comment: Server log will tell you what exactly went wrong, but my *hunch* is that you're missing curl extension.

Comment: just installed curl with :  sudo apt-get install php5-curl.    still not working. do i have to reset it or something ?

Comment: @Mjh  Please see my edit

Comment: its not a duplicate and i have an answer that is not in your link. please remove the duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first i had to add the curl  `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

But then, to restart the apache !!!

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

No restart- not working !

Answer (score 0):

Changing the file extension changes how the server handles serving the file when someone requests the file. E.g. if someone requests an image, it sends image headers to the receiver so it (usually the browser) knows to display it as an image. If someone requests a video, the server will send the appropriate headers to inform the receiver that a video is on its way.

In your case, changing from PHP to HTML will change how the server handles it, from parsing it as a PHP file to not parsing it as a PHP file when you change it to a .HTML file. This could signify that you have an error in your PHP code, or that your server isn't handling PHP files properly. The output you see when it's a HTML file is your php code being parsed as plaintext. This is bad and insecure as it could output your passwords to the user.

To check if your PHP code has errors, view the error log in the error log directory that's stated in your php.ini. Also, whilst you're developing, it may be worth setting display_errors to on so you don't see a blank screen when you get a coding error.