# not able to get the contents of the url

Tags: php, html

I am not able to get the contents from the link
http://raindrops.in/ainvvy/view/527a727a4251df44558b4567

I tried file_get_contents and curl given in the post [How do I get the HTML code of a web page in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php)

Please help me to get the content of the link. I want to save it into a variable.

Comment: can you show here what codes you already tried? And what are the errors encountered?

Comment: what did u get when you tried file_get_contents? and please show how you did it.

Comment: It may be that there is a test of referrer that will block your script from retrieving the contents

Comment: Its showing 403 forbidden error. This should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680709/file-get-contents-give-me-403-forbidden

Comment: I didn't get any errors but its not working and giving only the top bar of the page. Remaining contents are not coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, this website relies heavily on AJAX for its content, so getting just the source code (what you are doing with cUrl or file_get_contents will only give you an empty page.

You have 2 choices to get the "real" content (the player presentation) :

- understand the format and logic of those Ajax call and implement them. The AJAX call in your exemple can be done with cUrl

curl 'http://raindrops.in/rest/ainvvy/527a727a4251df44558b4567' -H 'Cookie: __utma=161727679.1871000365.1388669242.1388669242.1390391663.2; __utmb=161727679.3.10.1390391663; __utmc=161727679; __utmz=161727679.1390391663.2.2.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/20967366/not-able-to-get-the-contents-of-the-url' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: http://raindrops.in/ainvvy/view/527a727a4251df44558b4567' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' --compressed)

- or use a browser to actually interpret javascript and make the AJAX call. For this option, you can use Phantomjs http://phantomjs.org/ which is great to implement automation of browser behavior (this is a browser, a webkit implementation, that you can script in javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Following code is working for me.

```
echo @file_get_contents('http://raindrops.in/ainvvy/view/527a727a4251df44558b4567');
```

make sure you have **`allow_url_fopen = On`** in your php.ini file

Comment: allow_url_fopen is already ON but still it is giving the same problem for me. I got only the first content of the first page which is the top bar

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `allow_url_fopen = on` in you php.ini file, you can use "cUrl" to fetch the remote page.
[cUrl Manual Page](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php/)

Comment: Its already ON..and I have tried by using the curl also but its not working..please help me out

Comment: What's the code you're using to fetch the page with cUrl ? Did you turned cUrl on in your server ?

Comment: $url ="http://raindrops.in/ainvvy/view/527a727a4251df44558b4567? print=true";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
     echo curl_error($ch);
     echo "\n<br />";
     $contents = '';
     } else {
    curl_close($ch);
    }
 
if (!is_string($contents) || !strlen($contents)) {
echo "Failed to get contents.";
$contents = '';
}

    echo $contents;