# 403 error when using file_get_contents()

Tags: php, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to scrape some product details from a website using the following code:

```
$list_url = "http://www.topshop.com/en/tsuk/category/sale-offers-436/sale-799";
$html = file_get_contents($list_url);
echo $html;
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://www.topshop.com/en/tsuk/category/sale-offers-436/sale-799)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in
>   /homepages/19/d361310357/htdocs/shopaholic/rss/topshop_f_uk.php on
>   line 123

I gather that this is some sort of block by the website to prevent scraping. Is there a way around this - perhaps using cURL and setting a user agent?

If not, is there another way of getting basic product data like item name and price?

**EDIT**

The context of my code is that I'd eventually still want to be able to achieve the following:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by adding the following code...

```
ini_set('user_agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)');
```

...as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680709/file-get-contents-give-me-403-forbidden).

Answer (score -1):

You should use cURL , not the simple way with file_get_contents().
Use cURL and set up the proper http headers to mimic a proper http request (a real request).

P.S. : set up cURL to follow redirects . Here is the link to [cURL](https://php.net/curl)