# Simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot; &quot;

Tags: php, xml, curl

i tried to some the ways load data xml from URL before ask this question but all same failed . Same have some special characters in XML url . this is error

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot; &quot; in D://....;
```

And this is my code :

```
$url = 'http://website.com?xml&param1=1&param2=2';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$json = json_encode($xml);
echo $json;
```

Thanks every helping

Answer (score 1):

You could load the URL more simply using

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'http://website.com?xml&param1=1&param2=2';

$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($xml);
```

Edit:
There is some talk about error 403 in various places, one suggestions is to set the user agent prior to this call:

```
ini_set('user_agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)');
```

(Taken from [file_get_contents() give me 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680709/file-get-contents-give-me-403-forbidden))

Comment: Thansk you 
I think , my XML url had problem with special characters . When i use `curl `to get data and  `var_dump($data)` , I saw characters " " inside . I dont know reason because i can get data from another xml url normaly .

Comment: Thanks @Nigel Ren . I used follow it and result :

 `Warning: file_get_contents(http://website.com/entries.xml?key=0231cf3b3ef031e070b4e30fea881a0c63dd38f2&amp;project_id=192&amp;issue_id=8136&amp;from=2017-05-01&amp;to=2017-05-20&amp;oe=utf-8): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in D:\website\index.php on line 9
` . with 403 forbiden error , becasue this server which I'm not adminitrator cause i can set permision for it

Comment: `ini_set('user_agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)');` : Still not working and still same message old error;

Comment: The code works on your original URL, but this new URL doesn't, if this is the same for you, then it's something to do with the access to this resource.  Have you tried it in your browser and see what that gives you.

Comment: Thanks @Nigel Ren . I'll try