# decode json failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! error

Tags: php, json, decoding

I get `file_get_contents(https://koinex.in/api/ticker):failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  error`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680709/file-get-contents-give-me-403-forbidden

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$context = stream_context_create([ 
    'http'=> [ 
        'method'=> 'GET', 
        'user_agent'=> $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] 
    ]
]); 

$data = json_decode(
    file_get_contents('https://koinex.in/api/ticker', false, $context)
);
```

The following `https://koinex.in/api/ticker` works from browser so it seems that all you need to set a `user_agent` to fool the server that the request is being made by a real user using a browser. Also read about [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php).