# Regarding "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"

Tags: php, http, curl, file-get-contents

Hear I am trying to access NSEIndia.com website URL "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftySmallcap50OnlineStockWatch.json".

this is working fine when I am opening this in browser but it is not working when I try to open this using php `file_get_contents`.

Please help me or suggest me what should I try another way so I will receive output of this URL in my code.

```
$url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftySmallcap50OnlineStockWatch.json";
echo file_get_contents( $url );
die;
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi, Did you get a solution??

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680709/file-get-contents-give-me-403-forbidden) answer for more info

Basically the webserver is configured in a way that blocks request from file_get_contents.

Maybe try curl?

In the linked question the following code is provided

```
    // create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```