# Microsoft Translator Using PHP

Tags: php, translation

I am work with Microsoft Translator now. I had tried this tutorial:

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/phptranslator.aspx
2. https://code.google.com/p/micrsoft-translator-php-wrapper/

And they do not working properly. I am connected to the internet as well, I couldn't connect to host in tutorial 1 and I got some errors in tutorial 2:

> Warning:
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\xampp\htdocs\translate\class\MicrosoftTranslator.class.php on line 158

Comment: Did you provide the proper authentication? If a service like this refused your request then it is almost certainly a problem on your side.

Comment: Yap, I have all needed : the account key, client app id, client secret. But not work at all :(

Comment: Can you tell me the errors you got in tutorial #1? Which host did you not connect to?

Also, are you sure you have the right ClientID and Client Secret? You can ensure them here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/gettingstarted1.aspx, and also make sure you've subscribed to the translator service.

Comment: Of course I had subscribed translator service, I got an error like this: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$error in C:\xampp\htdocs\translatorapiphp\AccessTokenAuthentication.php on line 49 and always got stuck in Exception message

Comment: Can you make sure CURL is installed in your PHP? Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php-xampp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem :

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$error
```

I resolved it by simply replacing :

```
if ( $objResponse->error )
```

by :

```
if ( isset($objResponse->error) )
```