# [RIAK-PHP-CLIENT]: Installing issues from github repository (./config)

Tags: php, database, web, webclient, riak

beginner with linux here but I am trying to follow some simple instructions for setting up a riak-php-client that will enable me to make my riak database and website communicate, i.e. fetch and display data to the website. The github repository of which I'm following:

https://github.com/basho/riak-php-client

I clone the repository, but at "Quick start" when trying to run

```
user@user-pc:~/riak-php-client $ ./config --with-curl
```

I end up getting the message "bash: ./config: No such file or directory", same story when I'm in home/riak-php-client/src. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The instruction to run

```
./configure --with-curl
```

is intended to show you how to enable curl in your local build of PHP, when compiling PHP from source.  The readme doesn't make that very clear.

The command

```
php -m | grep curl
```

will return 'curl' if your local PHP installation has curl enabled, if it is, just continue on with the examples in the readme.  If not there are other questions on stack overflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php-xampp) that may help