# Why is CURLOPT_CAINFO defined in the command line, but not in web?

Tags: php, curl

I tried running a PHP script that var_dumps CURLOPT_CAINFO in the command line. It gives a value. However, when I put the same code in a PHP file for use with Apache, it says CURLOPT_CAINFO is undefined. What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enable CURL in the PHP installation that Apache points to. See also: [How to enable cURL in PHP / XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php-xampp). Check the settings by calling:

```
phpinfo();
```

in your script and look at the differences in modules that are enabled.