# how to use curl in fatfree php

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use or implement php curl in an application I'm building using fatfree php framework. I tried to use curl as in my procedural code but I can't have it working in fatfree. Is there any plugin that I can use in fatfree to subsitute for php curl, or can someone help me on how to use curl in fatfree. This is my first post on this site, I would really appreciate any help from this community.

Comment: cURL is included on PHP, it's not depending of the framewok you use

Comment: we do not know your environment. Curl is a php feature which may be disabled. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php-xampp

Comment: @mmm, you are right. I just rewrite my code and I'm having results from my curl post request.