# Why does PHP refuse to enable cURL on Windows

Tags: php, curl, php-extension

I am using `PHP 5.5.25` with `Apache 2.4` on `Windows 7 x64` and I am unable to activate the cURL module. I have looked around and tried all I could think of. Please assist:

- In `php.ini`, the line `extension=php_curl.dll` is active and the file `php_curl.dll` is present in the extensions directory `C:\php\ext`
- In `php.ini` when I set `extension_dir = ext`, none of the extensions load. I get several messages when Apache starts, similar to `Unable to load dynamic library`ext\php_openssl.dll`- The specified module could not be found.`
- When I use the full path and set `extension_dir = C:\php\ext`, all the extensions load fine, except for cURL. I get the error: `Unable to load dynamic library`C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll`- The specified module could not be found.`
- I have tried renaming the extension to `php_curl.new.dll` and adjusting `php.ini` but I get an error message about the new filename. I have also downloaded a fresh new copy of the DLL from `windows.php.net`, but that made no difference.
- I have checked the file permissions for `php_curl.dll` (Right-click on the file >> Properties >> Security tab) and they are the same as the permissions for extensions that load successfully
- I have copied and pasted `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` from the PHP bin directory to the System32 and SysWOW64 directories as instructed by a response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php-xampp)
- I am certain that I am editing the right `php.ini` since the PHP startup error messages changed when I changed the `extension_dir` value from `ext` to `C:\php\ext` as I explained above.
- I have made sure to restart the Apache server between `php.ini` configuration changes.
- If in a PHP script I execute `var_dump(file_exists('C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll'));`, I get `boolean True` so PHP can see the file!

What else could explain why the cURL module is not enabled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you'll need `libssh2.dll` in your `PATH` too.

Comment: That worked! Copying random DLLs from `C:\php` to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` may cause a problem later because when I change PHP versions I won't remember to overwrite those copies with the new versions' DLLs.  I am thinking instead of adding `C:\php` to the Windows PATH variable. This way all PHP DLL files can stay together and be easier to maintain. Do you see any big downside to that?

Comment: No, that's a sensible thing to do. Although you mean `C:\php\ext`, right? It's a long time since I've run PHP on Windows...

Comment: The extensions are in `C:\php\ext`, bu the DLLs Windows couldn't see are in `C:\php`

Comment: Placing this file in the same location as php.exe, and php.ini (together) resolved this issue.  Missed that little file.

Comment: Thanks!! saved my hours :)

Comment: It took me a long time to reach this answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Credit goes to @Steven Hilder for pointing me in the right direction.

The problem was that Windows could not see `libssh2.dll`, another DLL that was in PHP's directory. Copying this file to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and `C:\Windows\System32`, along with the other two DLL files from my OP (`libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`) worked.

I am uncomfortable with this solution though because when the time comes to update to a new PHP version I will have a harder time remembering to overwrite these DLLs with the new version.
Therefore, I decided to remove all 3 DLLs from the `System32` and `SysWOW64` directories.  Instead, I just added the PHP bin directory to the Windows' PATH variable, so that the next time the OS is looking for a missing file, it will also look in that directory. This has the added bonus that if a similar problem with another DLL occurs, it will be resolved automatically.

To add the PHP bin to Windows' PATH:

1. From the `Start Menu` search bar, search for and select `Advanced system settings`
2. Click `Environment Variables`.  Scroll down the list of System variables to select `Path` and click `Edit...` to open the current PATH setting
3. Append `;C:\php` or whatever directory has `php.exe` to the current setting (semi-colon is used to separate paths).

Answer (score 2):

on windows the cURL execution wants SSL certificate. may be because of that others error is showing.

Put the below code before curl_exec(curlHandle) to ignore checking for SSL certificate

```
//to ignore the SSL certificate in windows
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
```

Comment: The cURL module would not load at all, so no cURL function was available to my script.  My problem was that the OS needed but could not find `libssh2.dll`.