# I am trying to display some data from Socrata using Soda API and got the following message **Error "0" from server:**

Tags: php, socrata, soda

I am trying to display some data from Socrata using Soda API and got the following message

**Error "0" from server:**

What does this mean?

**This is my code:**

```
 $socrata = new Socrata("https://data.medicare.gov", $app_token);
 $params = array("\$where" => "starts_with(zip, $model->zipcode)");
 $response = $socrata->get("/resource/aeay-dfax.json",$params);
 ?> 
 <?= Html::encode($model->zipcode) ?>

 <h2>Results</h2>

  <?# Create a table for our actual data ?>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
    <?# Print rows ?>
    <?php foreach($response as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $row["lst_nm"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["fst_nm"] ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>

  <h3>Raw Response</h3>
  <pre><?= var_dump($response) ?></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error from Socrata is because of a type mismatch between your query and the available data. The `zip` column is treated as plain text so you must give it a string in your SoQL query as well. Simply wrap `$model->zipcode` in escaped quotes like so:

```
$params = array("\$where" => "starts_with(zip, \"$model->zipcode\")");
```

Otherwise, you'd be giving the query an integer. You could also use single quotes if you don't want to escape the double quotes.

Comment: I am getting the Error "0" from server after making that change

Comment: @samauto Do you have [cURL enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php-xampp) in your PHP installation?

Comment: I believe so I have XAMPP and I see it enabled in the php.ini file