# TYPO3 9 LTS Version 9.5.5 - Could not access remote resource https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am working with the current version Typo3 9.5.5, with PHP version: 7.3.2 and XAMPP 3.2.3 on Windows 7. In the backend interface under ADMIN TOOLS -> Extensions -> get preconfigured distributions I always get the error "Could not access remote resource https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz.". I have tried it with https://www.pagemachine.de/blog/wie-ihr-typo3-8-0-als-locales-testsystem-unter-windows-installer-unser-tutorial/#div-comment-4718 but unfortunately did not work. Does anyone have a solution?

[Edit] I would like to upload the whole file php.ini, but unfortunately I have not found a way to do this. It is not possible to put all the content of the php.ini here, because the character limit is 30000. I could just show the uncommented lines, but that would not be nice either.

A part of the C:\xampp\php\php.ini:

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
;...
;...
;...
; When the extension library to load is not located in the default extension
; directory, You may specify an absolute path to the library file:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/mysqli.so
;
; Note : The syntax used in previous PHP versions ('extension=<ext>.so' and
; 'extension='php_<ext>.dll') is supported for legacy reasons and may be
; deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please
; move to the new ('extension=<ext>) syntax.
;
; Notes for Windows environments :
;
; - Many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) or ext/ (PHP 5+)
;   extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5+).
;   Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
extension=bz2
extension=curl
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate curl in your XAMPP installation. Maybe this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php-xampp) can help you with that.

If you have Windows 10 Professional I can highly recommend [DDEV-Local](https://www.drud.com/get-started/) which gives you a solid base for local development. It should also work with Windows 10 Home.
In case you need help with DDEV, the #DDEV channel in [TYPO3 Slack](https://my.typo3.org/about-mytypo3org/slack/) is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem** by adding
(1) the line "*extension = php_curl.dll*" in the module settings part

and by updating
(2) the file "*curl-ca-bundle.crt*" in the line *; curl.cainfo = "C: \ xampp \ apache \ bin \ curl-ca-bundle.crt* "does not exist in the Xampp directory (including subdirectories). Therefore, download the file "*cacert.pem*" expilicitly (just google) and **replace** the line *; curl.cainfo = "C: \ xampp \ apache \ bin \ curl-ca-bundle.crt"* with *curl.cainfo = "C: \ xampp \ cacert.pem "*. Put the "*cacert.pem*" file in the directory "*C: \ xampp *".
(3) Also **replace** the line: *openssl.cafile = "C: \ xampp \ apache \ bin \ curl-ca-bundle.crt"* with *openssl.cafile = "C: \ xampp \ cacert.pem"*. It should work then.